# Digram Generation/Creation: Languages/Grammars

Tags: diagrams, grammar

Hey, does anyone know if there's any tools for generating nice uniform grammar representation diagrams like the ones on [json.org](http://www.json.org/)?

Or am i stuck with visio/photoshop doing them by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is the de facto standard for graph generation.